# Copy output from Google Colaboratory and Paste in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, copy-paste, spreadsheet

Given a [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) notebook with the following cell

```
url = 'https://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip'
extract_zip(download_url(url, '.'), '.')

movies_path = './ml-latest-small/movies.csv'
ratings_path = './ml-latest-small/ratings.csv'

print('movies.csv:')
print('===========')
print(pd.read_csv(movies_path)[["movieId", "genres"]].head())
```

The output is something like:

```
movies.csv:
===========
   movieId                                       genres
0        1  Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
1        2                   Adventure|Children|Fantasy
2        3                               Comedy|Romance
3        4                         Comedy|Drama|Romance
4        5                                       Comedy
```

I want to know if there is a straightforward way to copy and paste these results into an Excel spreadsheet.
The expected result in this example is a spreadsheet with two columns and 5 lines.

Everything I tried (different copy+paste shortcuts), pasted everything in the same cell or, in the best cases, pasted the results split by line but not by column.

Note that I know that exporting the result as CSV is possible, but that is not what I'm looking for.

I need it for a very manual (and human-centric) process for now. Someone will open the colab, execute the cell, perform some (small) adjustments in the code, execute again, and paste again (many times).

This step must be manual, but copying and pasting one value per cell is annoying.

No automation for this phase, but shortcuts, hidden Excel menus, and pandas tricks are welcome.

System:

- Windows 11
- Microsoft Excel